# Using the tombstone as a check box

Tags: soft-question, notation

The first time I was introduced to the $\Box$ symbol in my first year of university I immediately thought it's a neat way how to mark that I have read and understood the proof:

[image: Checked tombstone]

As I later learned, to my surprise, that's not at all [the origin or the purpose of the symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tombstone_(typography)). To this day, I use it that way - reading a text *without* ticking the tombstones would just feel wrong!

Of course, other people found this usage funny, some even thought I can't possibly be serious about it, which seems surprising, after all, *it is a checkbox*! This leads to the following question:

**Question**: How common is this? Or rather, have you encountered this usage at all, or am I commiting mathematical blasphemy and causing Paul Halmos to turn over in his grave?

This is, I suppose, a question that is possibly unsuitable for this site, in which case I apologize, just always wondered about this and don't know a better place to ask than Math.SE.

Comment: This is a rather recent use. Even the concept of "checking" something is very recent (in a tombstone or elsewhere), in the spirit of systematic task scheduling, children of "Taylor methodology" I would say.

Comment: @JeanMarie That is actually a very interesting idea. Any links/references on it? It wouldn't have to be a tick though - could be an X as in tic-tac-toe, a game that supposedly has roots in the Roman empire

Comment: For much of my early life I used a filled-in box for the same purpose: $\blacksquare$. I was only introduced to the hollow box $\Box$ when I started looking at arXiv papers, and I feel that both variants are equally common. But I don't check the box. My brain is too big for that.